# How to show a confirmation message when Windows shuts down?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005

I want a custom confirmation message when the user shuts down Windows, but there should be some points:

1. When the user is trying to shut down, it should show the confirmation message.
2. If the user hits OK, then it will be shut down.
3. If they hit the Cancel button,  then also the window should shut down and some unique value should be made in a database (SQL server).

Comment: Please identify which Windows version? I'm sorry you completely lost me on last point what does it mean? Please be more clear.

Comment: ok avirk ...it is applicable all window like xp,window server 2003 ,windows7 and last point is when user hit cancel button then also window shut down and some unique number go in database

Comment: And what kind of those numbers are?

Comment: any unique number like 123145

Comment: any idea friends how to do this?

Comment: That kind of behaviour is up to each application to implement, doing it that way is *easy* if you have the sourcecode. There is nothing you can do to intercept an applications shutdown (without doing some **deep** integration into explorer.exe and probably windows itself (if it's possible at all))

Comment: The only way to do this is to have another application that monitors running applications and launches when it detects that "your" application is no longer running. In either case it's either **OffTopic** and belongs on stackoverflow if you want to code your own solution or **Not a real question** - Voting to close.

Comment: ok but im read that we can change in shutdown script file is that possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you need it?

Windows has already a built-in feature called shutdown event tracker. It is enabled by default on server OSes, and you can also enable it through the group policies (for example with `gpedit.msc`) on desktop versions of Windows.

[image: A screenshot of Local Group Policy Editor showing "Display Shutdown Event Tracker" option]

It gives you the ability to:

1. Avoid that the user shuts down the machine by mistake by showing the dialog box like:
   [image: A screenshot of a Shut Down Windows dialog under Windows 2008]
2. Track the shutdown events through Event Viewer with a more detailed view.

For example:

- Without the event tracker enabled, you have:

> *Kernel-Power:109* The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition.
>   *Kernel-General:13* The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2011‎-‎09‎-‎10T00:23:20.247232500Z.

- With Shutdown Event Tracker, you have:

> *USER32:1074* The process Explorer.EXE has initiated the restart of computer <Computer name> on behalf of user <Domain name>\<User name> for the following reason: Loss of network connectivity (Unplanned)
>   Reason Code: 0x4050014
>   Shutdown Type: restart

From here, if you're a developer or if you're able to hire one, you can easily create a tool which will scan Windows Events and import the significant information into your database, including the user who started the shutdown, or the reason.

Comment: ok mainma thnx for your valuable suggestion and advise

Comment: but that conformation pop up message how will i show?

Comment: @Atul: sorry, my answer was unclear on this point. See the last edit.

Comment: ok mainma .... thnx your suggestion it is show confirmation message when shut down window? and how will one unique value go in database ??

Comment: *"Does it show confirmation message when you shut down windows?"*: yes. *"How will one unique value go in database?"*: like I said in the last paragraph of my answer, it's up to you to build a tool which will extract data from Windows Event Log, transform it, and load it into a database.

Comment: ok mainma thank you thank you very very much for your valuable answer ....